# Общая и различная часть для двух действий

Tags: python

в процессе создания своей третьей программки, столкнулся с такой задачей: Есть условие и 2 действия, у которых различаются только первые строки, остальная часть у них одна и та же. Как сделать так, чтобы сначала выполнялись эти самые первые строки, а затем выполнялась общая часть, вне зависимости от действия, чтобы не писать два раза один и тот же код

```
if (b1 <0):
    print (y, '-(', b1, ')')
else:
    print (y, '-', b1)

    #общая часть для обоих условий
    print('D=', D)
    print('Ответ:')
    print('x1=', x1)
    print('x2=', x2)
```

Comment: Ну, просто уберите отступ у общей части, наверное?